# C# XmlTextReader not reading all elements and attributes

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I'm trying to read data from an xml file and display it in a text box, but it is only displaying the last element/attribute, in this case "Endurance". Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Character>
  <Name
   Name="Test" />
   <Age
   Age="19" />
  <Class
  Class="Necromancer" />
  <Strength
  Strength="1" />
  <Dexterity
  Dexterity="2" />
  <Intelligence
  Intelligence="3" />
  <Speed
  Speed="4" />
  <Endurance
  Endurance="5" />
</Character>
```

My code for the reader is as follows

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
while (reader.Read())
{
   if (reader.HasAttributes)
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
     {
       reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
       switch (reader.Name)
       {
         case "Name":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Name: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         case "Age":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Age: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         case "Class":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Class: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         case "Strength":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Strength: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         case "Dexterity":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Dexterity: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         case "Intelligence":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Intelligence: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         case "Speed":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Speed: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         case "Endurance":
             DisplayBox.Text = "Endurance: " + reader.Value + "\n";
             break;
         default:
             break;
       }
     }
         reader.MoveToElement();
  }
}
```

So whenever I click the button to display the data, the only thing that shows up in the text box is Endurance: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to replace

```
DisplayBox.Text =
```

with

```
DisplayBox.Text +=
```

Moreover all of the switch conditions are very similar. So you can use the following:

```
string[] supportedAttributes = new []{"Name", "Age", "Class", "Strength", "Dexterity", "Intelligence", "Speed", "Endurance"};
while (reader.Read())
{
   if (reader.HasAttributes)
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
     {
       reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
       if(supportedAttributes.Any(a=>a == reader.Name))
           DisplayBox.Text += string.Format("{0}: {1} \n", reader.Name, reader.Value);
     }
     reader.MoveToElement();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I not directly answering your question, but instead offering an alternative way to write your code.

The `switch` statement, in particular, repeats itself and the repetition can be removed.

Also using a `switch` statement locks your code in to particular values. You can't dynamically change the list of attribute names that you want to use - maybe for a different language, for example.

Here's my code:

```
var xd = XDocument.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);

var query =
    from xe in xd.Descendants()
    from xa in xe.Attributes()
    let r = map(xa.Name.ToString(), xa.Value)
    where r != null
    select r;

DisplayBox.Text = String.Join("", query);
```

Now the only thing missing is the definition for the `map` function. This is where the code gets a bit edgy.

First start with the names you're looking for:

```
var names = new []
{
    "Name", "Age", "Class",
    "Strength", "Dexterity", "Intelligence",
    "Speed", "Endurance", 
};
```

Now we just have to define a couple of variables responsible for the mapping:

```
var nameMap =
    names
        .ToDictionary(
            n => n,
            n => (Func<string, string>)
                (t => String.Format("{0}: {1}\n", n, t)));

Func<string, string, string> map =
    (n, v) =>
        nameMap.ContainsKey(n) ? nameMap[n](v) : null;
```

It's a little bit tricky, but it nicely separates the list of names from the final query to get your data and will keep your code cleaner for the parts that need to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    DisplayBox.Text =
```

you should use like

```
   DisplayBox.Text +=
```

It shall do the required.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are looping through all the nodes.

Finally loop stops at final node. Thats nothing but Endurance node.

So you will see the result as Endurance.

You need to check for specific condition and if it is satisfies then you need to come out the loop.

Or

If you want to show all the values in the textbox then follow **@Kostya** and **@Furqan** answers.